# Morris bar resize while print

Tags: javascript, css, printing, morris.js

I have problem about how to print my Morris bar result. In html, everything is fine, but when i want to print, it seems like everything doesn't fit anymore.
Here's what i do :

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    window.print();
}
</script>

    <div id="bar" class="bar" class="col-sm-12"></div>

    <script>
    Morris.Bar({
      barGap:4, // Espace entre les colonnes
      barSizeRatio:0.90, // Largeur des colonnes
      element: 'bar',
      data: dataChart,
      xkey: 'y',
      ykeys: ['a'],
      //barColors: ['#0B62A4','#f75b68','#4DA74D','#646464'],
      labels: ['Actuel'],
    });
    </script>
```

Here's what i get when it's normal view while printing (not good, too large) :

[image: Heberger image]

And if i refresh on printing page, the size rechange again (just fine):

[image: Heberger image]

It seems like something wrong with svg, because that's what i get after refreshing and it's the right size :

[image: Heberger image]

If you have any ideas, let me know.

Thank you for your help and time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar question was reported: https://github.com/morrisjs/morris.js/issues/652

Accordingly with that link, you can use:

```
<div id="myBar" class="col-sm-6"></div>
```

in JavaScript:

```
var bar = Morris.Bar({......});
```

and finally:

```
$('#myBar').resize(function () { bar.redraw(); });
```

Comment: Yes, i know, i tried, but still doesn't work, that's why i wanted some help.

Comment: Then you must do debug in Chrome Console or other browser's console